# Javascript - get all table -> tr values

Tags: javascript, html-table

```
<table>
  <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
  <tr><td>bar</td></tr>
  <tr><td>abc@yahoo.com</td></tr>
</table>
```

Can anybody tell me how to write a Javascript line to only grab the email address in the table below, I've been searching a lot, but all I come across is tutorials which use "id" in either table on in td .. I want to do it without having an id .. please help

Comment: Will the email adress always be in the same row/col?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
var last = rows[rows.length - 1];
var cell = last.cells[0];
var value = cell.innerHTML
```

Try it yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/ReyNx/.

Obviously you'll have to change `document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]` to appropriately match your table

If you're using jQuery it's easier:

```
var value = $('table tr:last td').text();
```

For more info, see the [MDN DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference), which shows you which properties are available on which elements to traverse the DOM.

Answer (score 17):

No jQuery, `innerHtml` or other evil / heavy functions, just plain old JavaScript:

```
// Get the first table in the document.
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
// Get the third row of this table (0-index 3rd = 2)
var emailRow = table.rows[2];
// Get this element's content.
var emailContent = emailRow.firstChild.textContent;
```

You could write it in 1 line:

```
var emailContent = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].rows[2].firstChild.textContent;
```

---

If you want to find *all* email addresses in a table:

```
var emails = [];
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var rowText = rows[i].firstChild.textContent;
    if (~rowText.indexOf('@')) { // If the content of the row contains a '@' character (This could be replaced with a regex check)
            // Also, I personally prefer to use '~' over '> -1' for indexOf(), but both would work.
        emails.push(rowText);
    }
}
console.log(emails);
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cnTzM/)**

Comment: To whomever did, If you are going to downvote me, at least have the decency to tell me why. I could learn from it, or improve my answer.

Comment: The only problem I can see with this answer is that `textContent` is not x-browser AFAIK (`innerText` in IE < 9), but that's not worthy of a downvote from my POV, so a +1 from me to compensate :).

Comment: @Matt: Much appreciated!
I appear to be getting a relatively massive amount of downvotes today :-/ I wonder if it's someone in particular doing it. Who knows...

Answer (score 5):

If like me you want to get the text from all the first column items in all the tables on the page then use this.

```
jQuery('table tr td').each( function( cmp ) { 
    console.log( jQuery(this).text() ); 
} );
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to extract all emails, but I had more than 1,000 rows and 17 columns/cells.

I used vanilla js, made some adjustments to get my desired output

```
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]; //first table
    var rows = table.rows; 
    //loop through rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i+=1) {
        var emailTr = rows[i];
        var emailTd = emailTr.cells[2]; //target third column/cell
        var email = emailTd.innerHTML; //get the value
        console.log(email + ', ');

        var node = document.createElement("span"); // create span element
        node.innerHTML = email + ', '; // desired output
        document.body.appendChild(node); // display to document body
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to give it a common class. Try:

```
<table>
  <tr><td class="email">foo</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="email">bar</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="email">abc@yahoo.com</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
function getEmail(){
    var email = new Array();
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('email');
    for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        email.push(arr[i].innerHTML);
    }
    alert(email.join(','));
}
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aki143S/rEVu2/5/)

Comment: Still not working man, he want only email, not any other text.

Comment: But his td has only email inside it

Comment: And He want only that Email Address, check the code which one got accepted. He is showing only one email address in alert box.

Comment: hi akhil , thanks for the help , but the page m working on does not have any id or class associated with any part of the table ..

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using vanilla Javascript (no libraries such as jQuery), and that this is the only table on the page, you can use the following code to select the third tr in the table, then find out what the td element contains

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var emailTr = table.rows[2];
var emailTd = emailTr.cells[0];
var email = emailTd.innerHTML;
```

jQuery would make this easier

```
var email = $("table").children("tr:eq(2)").children("td").html();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution in case you are using or plan to use [**jQuery library**](http://jquery.com/).

Given the email is always in the third row and first column (like in your example) then you can do as follows:

```
email = $('table tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child').html();
```

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/8e980)

Comment: This is not necessarily a jQuery question.

Comment: Oops, I'm assumed it was, will add a warning for that.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the `<tr>` elements. Loop through each one and compare the `innerHTML` against a regex that matches email addresses.

```
var emailAddresses = [];
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML.match(/yourEmailRegex/g)) {
        emailAddresses[emailAddresses.length] = cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Find the appropriate regular expression here http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 0):

in my case i want fifth column value of last row

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
var last = rows[rows.length - 1];
var cell = last.cells[4];
console.log(cell.textContent);
```